# Functions whose $n^{th}$ Derivatives form a cycle

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, periodic-functions

The simplest example of this is $e^x$ which we could say has period 1 (it is its own derivative).
$e^{-x}$ would have period 2.

Using similar constructions, I can get a function that has a derivative of period $n$ by doing $e^{x\cdot (1)^{1/n}}$

Is this the only way to get periodic derivatives?

**Note:** I am treating sin and cos as special cases of this when $n=4$

Is there a proof to this effect?

Comment: The space of functions satisfying $f^{(n)}=f$ has dimension $n$ (dimensions of solution spaces is an important consideration in differential equations), and there are $n$ distinct $n$th roots of unity.

Comment: There aren't any.

Comment: @AndréNicolas why not though?

Comment: The answer is presumably being typed by anon. If not, recall how to solve linear homogeneous DE with constant coefficients.

Comment: Expanding a little on "why not" : If we consider the differential equation $y^{(n)} = y$, we can use the characteristic method to solve this. Namely, make the ansatz $y = e^{\lambda x}$.  Then $e^{\lambda x}(\lambda^n -1) = 0$.  The zeros are the $n$th roots of unity.

Comment: The other thing to note is that a solution to a differential equation of order $n$ is determined by initial conditions on $y, y', \ldots, y^{(n-1)}$, and therefore the space of solutions has dimension $n$.  Thus once you have solutions of the form $e^{\lambda x}$ for $n$ different $\lambda$ (and these are easily seen to be linearly independent), all solutions are linear combinations of these.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $f^{(n)}(x)=f(x)$ for all $x$. 
Let $g(x) = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\xi^{-k} f^{(k)}(x)$, where $\xi^n=1$.
Then $g'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\xi^{-k} f^{(k+1)}(x) = \xi\sum_{k=1}^{n}\xi^{-k} f^{(k)}(x)=\xi g(x)$.
We already know all solutions of  $y'=c y$ and conclude that $g(x)=a e^{\xi x}$.

If we additionally assume that $\xi$ is *primitive*, we find for $0\le m<n$ that
$$ \sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\xi^{-mk} f^{(k)}(x)= a_m e^{\xi^m x}$$
Adding all equations leads to
$$n f(x) = \sum_{m=0}^{n-1} a_m e^{\xi^m x}.$$